# некорректная работа Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Некорректно работает `Shared Preferences`. Ниже код, постарался максимально подробно расписать (проблема описана в конце).

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ct++; //считаю нажатия
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(ct)); //устанавливаю количество нажатий
        lvl.setText("Ваш уровень: "+String.valueOf(uroven)); //показываю уровень(0,1,2....n)
        zv.setText(zvanie); //показываю текущее звание
        pb.setMax(MAX); //устанавливаю макс значение progress bar
        pb.setProgress(ct); //устанавливаю значение progress bar

        if (ct ==101 || ct == 201 || ct==301 ) {  
            uroven++;  //прибавляю уровень 
        }

        if (ct>0) {
            zvanie = "новичок";
            MAX = 100;// макс знач прогресс бараа

        } else if (ct>100) {
           zvanie = "средний";
           MAX = 200;

        } else if (ct>200) {
            zvanie = "профессионал";
            MAX = 300;
        }
```

**Далее сохраняю значения:**

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mStart = getSharedPreferences(COUNT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStart.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNT, ct);
    editor.apply();

    mUroven = getSharedPreferences(UROVEN,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = mUroven.edit();
    editor1.putInt(UROVEN, uroven);
    editor1.apply();

    mZvanie = getSharedPreferences(ZVANIE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = mZvanie.edit();
    editor2.putString(ZVANIE, zvanie);
    editor2.apply();

    mProgres = getSharedPreferences(PROGRESS,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = mProgres.edit();
    editor3.putInt(PROGRESS, MAX);
    editor3.apply();
```

**И в onCreate делаю так:**

```
mStart = getSharedPreferences(COUNT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //получаю кол-во нажатий
ct = mStart.getInt(COUNT,0);

mUroven = getSharedPreferences(UROVEN,Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //получаю уровень
uroven = mUroven.getInt(UROVEN,0);

mZvanie = getSharedPreferences(ZVANIE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //получаю звание
zvanie = mZvanie.getString(ZVANIE, "новичок");

mProgres = getSharedPreferences(PROGRESS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//получаю макс знач поргрессбара
MAX = mProgres.getInt(PROGRESS,0);

pb.setMax(MAX); //устанавливаю макс знач прогресс бара
pb.setProgress(ct); //устанавливаю значение прогрессбара
tv.setText(String.valueOf(ct)); //устанавливаю в текствью последнее значение нажатий
lvl.setText("Ваш уровень: "+String.valueOf(uroven)); //устанавливаю уровень
zv.setText(zvanie); //устанавливаю звание
```

Так вот проблема заключается в том, что после запуска приложения:

- не устанавливаются значения прогрессбара
- звание устанавливается как то странно, а именно если не набрать до звания средний, то звание сохраняется, а если звание профессионал, то при запуске приложения устанавливается звание средний

Comment: Давать переменным русские названия в английской транскрипции, такое себе. Возьмите за правило давать названия только на английском языке.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Но вопрос в другом.

Comment: я бы вам советовал использовать одно хранилище а не несколько, так будет проще отслеживать изменения. так же я бы предложил посмотреть в проводнике студии на файлы которые вы сохранили и что там сохранено

Comment: Для сохранения каждой переменной создавать отдельный SharedPreferences совершенно не правильно!

Comment: @Andrew - спасибо! Действительно, сделав одно хранилище все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибкой было для каждой переменной делать отдельное хранилище.
Нужно было сделать вот так:

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //создать одно хранилище и в него вложить переменные
    mStart = getSharedPreferences(START, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStart.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNT, ct);
    editor.putInt(UROVEN, uroven);
    editor.putString(ZVANIE,zvanie);
    editor.putInt(PROGRESS, MAX);
    editor.apply();
}
```

А в `onCreate` вытащить их:

```
mStart = getSharedPreferences(START, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ct = mStart.getInt(COUNT,0);
uroven = mStart.getInt(UROVEN, 0);
zvanie = mStart.getString(ZVANIE, "новичок");
MAX = mStart.getInt(PROGRESS,0);
```